# Using mousewheel, scroll to the corresponding section, pure js

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, element, mousewheel

I have 3 sections which are fullpages with photos. when I use the mouse wheel once up or down, I want it to scroll to the corresponding section. I don't want to use some kind of ready js script. i would like to do it with pure js. how could i do that?

```
<section class="section1"></section>
<section class="section2"></section>
<section class="section3"></section>
```

Comment: Can't the user already do that by scrolling?

Comment: with one mouse wheel to scroll to another "page"? don't think so. With millions probably can!

Comment: You may be looking for something like CSS scroll snapping: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using window.location.href and locate the next section, something like this -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            //Logic to find the next section......
            //........
            window.location.href = "#section2"; //Your next section
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onscroll="myFunction()">
    <section class="section1"></section>
    <section class="section2"></section>
    <section class="section3"></section>
</body>
</html>
```